# How to take canned beans out of jar?

Tags: beans, canning

Is there any method to take canned beans out of the jar without spoiling the beans, as they are kind of sticking on each other?

Comment: Are these in a can or in a jar, you have used both words?

Comment: @TFD, they are in the jar. I used "canned" by mean of process not material.

Comment: How are you going to use them?  If you're going to be using them so that you don't want the starchy liquid, you can rinse them out.  (add water, shake a bit, pour out, repeat)

Answer (score 4):

Even though this question seems a little trivial, I have had the same problem.

Usually the beans will come out with just gentle shaking. They won't budge at first but after the suction is broken they will descend and can be shaken out.

Occasionally I have had to use a spoon. You are right that if you just scoop them out you will mash many of them. If you just work the utensil along the side of the jar you can break the suction and they should shake free.

If you do mash them you can always finish the job and make refried beans out of them.

Comment: I mashed most of them, so I will refer to your last sentence. Thank you for the advice.